# Headless chrome doesn't supporting viewing pdfs using selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless

Here I'm trying to verify pdf file displayed after clicking on the link in the page!! which is displayed externally in new window/tab (FYI:I'm facing this issue using headless chrome!!)

Environment:

```
Centos 7
selenium-webdriver 3.12.0
ChromeDriver 2.40
Chrome 67.0
```

Chrome preferences:

```
chromePreferences.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePreferences.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
chromePreferences.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
chromePreferences.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
chromePreferences.put("pdfjs.disabled", true);
```

Which is working fine without headless chrome!! Any help much appreciated..

Any workarounds for verifying pdf files opened using headless chrome..

Comment: I think it's chrome issue https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1872

Comment: Yes, I came across this one..

Comment: Yes, I see the same thing. I'm glad this post exists to confirm the issue I was seeing.